# Emacs function to message the python function I'm in

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

I'm editing some Python code with rather long functions and decided it would be useful to quickly get the function name without scrolling up. I put this bit of code together to do it. Is there something built in to emacs in general, or the standard python mode in particular, which I can use instead?

```
(defun python-show-function-name()
  "Message the name of the function the point is in"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-defun)
    (message (format "%s" (thing-at-point 'line)))))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may find decent results with [which-function-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Which-Function.html):

> Which Function mode is a minor mode
>   that displays the current function
>   name in the mode line, updating it as
>   you move around in a buffer.
>
> To either enable or disable Which
>   Function mode, use the command M-x
>   which-function-mode. This command is
>   global; it applies to all buffers,
>   both existing ones and those yet to be
>   created. However, it takes effect only
>   in certain major modes, those listed
>   in the value of which-func-modes. If
>   the value is t, then Which Function
>   mode applies to all major modes that
>   know how to support it—in other words,
>   all the major modes that support
>   Imenu.

Although I see it getting a little confused in one Python file that I have here...

Comment: Thanks, that's ideal. It looks like it mostly works in python-mode although it reports the class you're working in rather than the function, and you have to enable it, as it's not in 'which-func-modes' by default.

Comment: You can also just call `(which-function)` if you want to get the function name but not use the minor mode.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `py-beginning-of-def-or-class`?

```
(defun python-show-function-name()
  "Message the name of the function the point is in"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (py-beginning-of-def-or-class)
    (message (format "%s" (thing-at-point 'line)))))
```

I find it gives me better results than your `beginning-of-defun`, but if that's not the problem you're having, then maybe I'm just seeing another symptom of the cause of the wonkiness in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782357/emacs-function-to-message-the-python-function-im-in/782413#782413).

Answer (score 0):

C-c C-u (py-goto-block-up) might be what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires moving in the buffer, which may not be what poster wants...

Comment: That's where save-excursion comes in.